# Why flexible widget not working with column widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Here is the code, everything works except Flexible widget...

This Flexible code doesn't work as expected. I can't find a solution on this. Don't know if was done in wrong fashion.

```
   Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Flexible(
              flex: 1,
              child: Hero(
                tag: 'title',
                child: Image.asset(
                  'assets/png/ClassAlerts.png',
                  width: 250,
                ),
              ),
            ),

            Flexible(
              flex: 3,
              child: Image.asset(
                'assets/png/mobile_application.png',
                width: 350,
              ),
            ),

           // More elements are there but I had to remove them
           // because got an error saying most part of this post was code.
          ],
        ),
```

Output
[image: Screenshot of this code[1]]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't cleared what kind of layout you want. If you want it all to be centered in the screen, then just add

`Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,......)`

For spaces between the elements you can put

`SizedBox(height: x)`

This creates an empty box which spaces the elements

Answer (score 1):

It might be something with your images.

Try this, it works with placeholders

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        // ClassAlert Title
        Flexible(
          flex: 1,
          child: Hero(tag: 'title', child: Placeholder()),
        ),

        // Page Image
        Flexible(
          flex: 3,
          child: Placeholder(),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```